# AutoLayout in GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need GMSMapView in a particular view. Here viewForGMSMapView is my UIView. I used the below code.

```
 let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(viewForGMSMapView.bounds, camera: camera)

mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true;


mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
 viewForGMSMapView.addSubview(mapView)
```

It helps to fix in my view. But when device screensize increases it fails. How to autolayout this GMSMapView. I need it to fit in my View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be `true`, you need to set an appropriate `autoresizingMask` so it resizes or shrinks correctly.

Try:

```
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Otherwise, you need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` and set up constraints for the map view.